# Loading flowplayer in overlay and adding clip programmatically

Tags: jquery, flowplayer, jquery-tools

Flowplayer js version: 3.2.4
Flowplayer flash swf version: 3.2.5

I am loading up the flowplayer in an overlay as such

```
$(function() {

    var pp = $f(
        "videoContent", 
        "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf"
    );

    var p = $("#overlay").overlay({
        api:true,
        onLoad: function() {
            var c = {url:'http://vod01.netdna.com/vod/demo.flowplayer/flowplayer-960.mp4'};                 
            pp.addClip(c, 0);
            pp.load();
        },
        onClose: function(){
            pp.unload();
        }
    });

    $("#open").click(function(){
        p.load();
    });

});
```

Everything but the add-clip functionality is standard set by flowplayer as an example on their site. Note sure why the clip is not being added.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pp.play({'url':'videos/file-name.mp4'},0);
```

The addClip method doesn't work the way it should seem to.